# FTPClient (apache.commons) isn't uploading or deleting my files

Tags: java, android

The below code gets down to the "Start uploading file" and "Trying to delete file from server..." and then never uploads nor delete the file if calling "onFileCreate" or "onFileDelete", also doesn't throw any errors to give any ideas of where it's being held up.  I've waited over 5 minutes for it to do something, nothing.  Does anyone know of anything I can put in to give me more of an idea about whats going on and ultimately get through the upload and respectively, the delete?

```
 public void onFileCreate(File file) {

                try {
                FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                System.out.println("File Created! - Do Work!" + file);
                 ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                 ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                 ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                 ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                 String filename = file.getPath();
                 System.out.println("Start uploading file");
                 boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(filename, inputStream);
                 inputStream.close();
                 if (done) {
                     System.out.println("The file was uploaded successfully: " + file);
                 }
                  ftpClient.isConnected();
                  ftpClient.logout();
                  ftpClient.disconnect();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }


            }


            @Override
            public void onFileDelete(File file) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("File removed: Do Work!");

                    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

                     ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                     ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                     ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                     ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                     String filename = file.getPath();
                     System.out.println("Trying to delete file from server...");
                     boolean done = ftpClient.deleteFile(filename);
                     if(done){
                     ftpClient.isConnected();
                     ftpClient.logout();
                     ftpClient.disconnect();
                     System.out.println("File deleted from server: " + file);
                     }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
```

Below is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot....  I was using the full file path (instead of the filename) for the storeFile command.

instead of:

```
   String filename = file.getPath();
```

it has to be:

```
   String filename = file.getName();
```

The first string command is the remote location so obviously the local file path is not going to work.